Esc Connections
I have bought an esc from atomrc (BLS2in110A2~4S) and can’t work out what the connectors are!
Here’s a link to the product:
https://atomrc.com/products/atomrc-flying-fish-2in-1-esc?_pos=3&_sid=d68689ecf&_ss=r
The size of the inside is 0.65 centimetres by 0.35
I have tried to email the manufacturer, but they did not understand my question
On the side of the servo connection, it says ‘1’ and ‘MXJ’. If that means anything, please let me know! This connector is 4.25 mills wide

Do you mean what model the physical port connectors are, or do you mean what the pin layout/order is? I'm not positive, but based on the photo, the motor connectors look like 3-pin JST-XH connectors.

You should email them directly. The photo is too indistinct to make out the connectors on the board for certain.

For anyone interested, the connectors were JST-Ph 2.0mm 3-Pin Connectors:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B09LPXGRLG/ref=ewc_pr_img_1?smid=AOXZIQW4RHZR1&psc=1
And:
https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/232695637343
